# Controlling stepper motor speed & direction with single L298N H-Bridge

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I'm in planing phase of my project. I have this motor: US-17HS4401 Stepper Motor (bipolar i think, has 4 wires). Can I use a single L298N H-Bridge motor to drive it. As in control both speed, direction and position of it ? I found many examples but all use a potentiometer to control speed by controlling voltage. Which is not good for me since I want to control the speed/position/direction using a Particle Photon module.

I will have a Particle Photon module drive this setup. I have two baskets sitting on top of each other, max total weight of the top one will be ~1KG this motor would be used to rotate the top basket left/right 45 degrees from it's starting position. But I also need to control how fast it rotates left/right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a bipolar stepper motor requires an H-bridge per phase. Fortunately for you, the L298N is a dual H-bridge, just right for your 2-phase (4-wire) motor.

Comment: Thank. Great news than.